Mist maker water indicator
I'm trying to understand the principles behind an ultrasonic atomizer (mist maker) I've bought. I have zero experience in electronics so be kind :)
The atomizer is using a rod sticking about 10 [mm] above the vibrating disk, the rod is isolated, only the tip is exposed.
After hard work trying to remove the epoxy to uncover the board I've damaged it so I don't know if there were any writing on some microchips.
My question is - what sort of component is most likely to use a rod to check for water?
I want to design my own board and reduce the distance between the disk and the sensor


Can you show us a picture of the other side of the board?

Added one for you, the slot on top the where the rod sits

Most likely it's a resistive or capacitive sensor (the latter so the rod doesn't corrode away, since it will be immersed in water during much of its active life). A capacitive sensor would also make it easier to use a single rod since there would be a lot of capacitance between the piezo disk and the water  in the reservoir. Since this involves some kind of connection between the power supply and the water, it's more appropriate where the power supply is electrically isolated (otherwise a float sensor might be better if the circuit is directly powered by the mains without any galvanic isolation).
Probably the component that was broken off the board (to the left of the 'rod' connection) was a series capacitor. There's also a series 1kΩ resistor.
The idea would be to detect the current flowing through the rod when it is immersed vs. not immersed when an AC signal is applied. This could be easily done with an ASIC or a small MCU in the form of that 8-pin DIP IC. Or it could possibly even be a 555.
From an earlier question, here is a schematic of a resistive type:

A small MCU would probably be the best approach in the current year, assuming you're up to speed on that sort of thing.
